# Нужно переделать скрипт поворота камеры

Tags: c#, камера

Есть код для движения камеры за игроком и поворотом за указателем мыши. Нужно переделать чтобы камера могла поворачиваться только вправо и влево
Видео по которому делался скрипт: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xnst9RW6RB0

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    private float xRot;
    private float yRot;
    private float xCurrRot;
    private float yCurrRot;
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera fpcCamera;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject fpcObject;
    public float mouseSensetive;
    private float xRotVelocity;
    private float yRotVelocity;
    private float smoothDampTime=0.1f;
    
    
    void Start()
    {
        mouseSensetive=2f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        MouseMove();
    }

    private void MouseMove()
    {
        xRot+=Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")*mouseSensetive;
        yRot+=Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*mouseSensetive;
        xRot=Mathf.Clamp(xRot,-90,90);

        xCurrRot=Mathf.SmoothDamp(xCurrRot,xRot, ref xRotVelocity, smoothDampTime);
        yCurrRot=Mathf.SmoothDamp(yCurrRot,yRot, ref yRotVelocity, smoothDampTime);

        fpcCamera.transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler(-xCurrRot,yCurrRot,0f);
        fpcObject.transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler(0f,yCurrRot,0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Выполнение работ на заказ - не тут

Comment: Обновление камеры - в `LateUpdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить значение движения камеры по оси Y на ноль.

```
fpcCamera.transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler(-xCurrRot,0f,0f);
```